# Declare static and dynamic methods with same name in PHP

Tags: php, oop

Is there some way to declare static and dynamic methods with same name in PHP?

Comment: You should elaborate. It is not clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - is it possible to declare a method static and nonstatic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331616/php-is-it-possible-to-declare-a-method-static-and-nonstatic)

Comment: This is a perfectly fine question and I just found it on google while asking myself the very same thing.

Answer (score 2):

No. You cannot declare 2 functions with the same name, even if they have different footprint. You'll get a fatal error like this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare Classname::methodname() in yourfile.php

Comment: But as I know in the PHP 7 you can't call static function from dynamic context, maybe we will have this declaration possibility after this changes?

Comment: Why? You can't call methods that require 1 parameter without the parameter, but that doesn't mean you can declare methods without and with one. So calling a certain footprint might be changing, declaring them still isn't in the books.