# Can I overriden static members (non-static properties and non-static methods)?

Tags: php, class, oop, static, overriding

With instance members (non-static) I know we can, but with static members I DON'T KNOW IF WE CAN, if we can, is it good practice?

Comment: hi, might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331616/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-method-static-and-nonstatic-in-php

Comment: hi @jspcal, nop, I say override static with static, not mix

Comment: Yes, you can override static methods. Try it and see.

Comment: As noted, this can [easily be proven](https://3v4l.org/hN53J). You should be aware of [late static binding](https://3v4l.org/c70VB), however.

Comment: hi @Barmar, great (I already checked), if I would like to keep the parent functionality when I overwrite the parent static method in the child class, is it correct to use parent::parentStaticMethod() (I have doubts also on this)?

Comment: Hi @Chris Haas then, if I need to override static members, IS IT BETTER TO OPT FOR LATE STATIC BINDING?

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Comment: sorry, it's just emphasis

Comment: When you write a comment, there should be a little help link near by that will show you how to write **using emphasis** if you _really_ need to. But do consider if it is _really_ needed in the first place.

Comment: "Better" is subjective. Read the PHP article on LSB, make sure you understand it, and see if it even applies to your situation. Some people, including myself, generally prefer to avoid static methods whenever possible, and doubly so with inheritance. But that is a personal preference, and they are a 100% valid language feature.

Comment: "Some people, including myself, generally prefer to avoid static methods whenever possible, and doubly so with inheritance". This matters to me, as I don't have much experience. If you want to reference parent static members from a child class (considering I don't use LSB), do you use `parent::`(I want to be sure of `parent::` in this case to avoid unwanted behavior))?