# SilverStripe canCreate on an Extension

Tags: php, silverstripe

For pages that must always be on the website (only 1, not more, like a homepage), I wanted to make an extension. The page should be created when I run dev/build and cannot be created, deleted, unpublished or archived in the CMS. It can be edited however.

Everthing seems to work just fine except the `canCreate` function. It seems as this function doesn't do much for the CMS when it's on a(n) (Data)Extension. When I'm on .../admin/pages/add I can still create the Page as many times as I want.

If I move the `canCreate` to the HomePage class, it does work. But I want it in my extension :-)

```
class OnePage extends DataExtension
{
    public function requireDefaultRecords()
    {
        if($this->canCreate()) {
            $page = $this->owner;

            $page->Title = $this->owner->className;
            $page->write();
            $page->publish('Stage', 'Live');
            $page->flushCache();
        }
    }

    public function canCreate($member = null)
    {
        return $this->owner->get()->count() == 0;
    }

    public function canDeleteFromLive($member = null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function canArchive($member = null)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
class HomePage extends Page
{
    private static $extensions = [
        'OnePage'
    ];
}
```

Am I doing this the right way or am I missing something?

**EDIT**

The `canCreate` method works just fine, so I can solve it like this;

```
class HomePage extends Page
{
    public function canCreate($member = null)
    {
        return $this->get()->count() == 0;
    }
}
```

This has the desired effect and works like a charm. However, the question is about putting the `canCreate` method in the Extension. That should work aswell, right?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `$this->owner->get()` won't work.  `$this->owner` always returns the actual object, not a DataList. It should work like:

```
public function canCreate() {

    $className = $this->owner->ClassName;

    return $className::get()->count() == 0;
}
```

BTW: if you plan to release a module of this please consider another name, I already have published https://github.com/wernerkrauss/silverstripe-onepage/ for making simple onepage-sites utilizing the SiteTree

Comment: Thanks for your response, however the `get` function does work. It is a [method](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataObject.html#_get) on `DataObject`. It returns a DataList, so could you change that in your answer? Besides that I do not plan on releasing it, just use it for my own. And this answer does not really answer my question, because I stated that the canCreate function does work, if you move it to the actual HomePage class

Comment: `get` is a static method, i doubt you can call it directly from the extension.

Comment: Calling a static method as a non-static method [is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10907777/6251886) Give it a try.